# Bootstrap 4 navbar - no height on mobile

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-4

How to set the bootstrap 4 navbar height in all viewport to 80px ?

I tried "min-height: 80px" in ".navbar" but the navbar is broken.

The sass code:

```
$navbar-bg:             #26f3fd;
$navbar-height:         80px;

.navbar {
    background-color: $navbar-bg;
    min-height: $navbar-height;
}
```

The html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="main-navbar" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbar-content">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?= esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">Accueil</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/juavenel/pen/xqMPrQ/

Comment: Please include the code in the question

Comment: This is a bootstrap 4 navbar normal usage code, with the min-height property in the css ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your navbar doesn't contain a `navbar-brand` so it's height collapses when the navbar stacks vertically.

This is a known issue that will be fixed in the beta release: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22230

The workaround is to include an empty placehold navbar-text or navbar-brand..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded py-3" id="main-navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <span class="navbar-text">&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbar-content">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accueil</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/FIKesgfDhL

Also, you can use vertical padding (`py-3`) instead to increase the height of the navbar and keep items vertically centered.